# If $\sum_{n\ge 1}n\mu(\{x:n\le f(x)<n+1\})<\infty$ then $\int_{X}fd\mu< \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How to show that if $\sum_{n\ge 1}n\mu(\{x:n\le f(x)<n+1\})<\infty$ than for nonnegative measureable $f$, $\int_{X}fd\mu< \infty $? What happens at $A_0=\{x:0\le f(x)<1\}$?
The reverse is clear, but what can I claim about the measure of set where $f(x)\ge 0$?
Maybe setting $A_{n}^{k}=\{x:n{1\over k}\le g(x)<(n+1)k\}$ with $g(x)={f(x)\over k}$ and try to reach a contradiction, but its really confusing to me.

I assume that if $\mu(\{x:0 \le f(x)<\epsilon\})=\infty$ than $\mu(\{x:0 \le f(x)<1\})=\mu(\{x:0 \le \epsilon f(x)<\epsilon\})$ and $\int_{X}{g(x)d\mu}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\int_{X}{1}_{A_n^{\epsilon}}\cdot g d\mu\le \epsilon\sum_{n\ge 0}(n+1)\mu(\{x:n\epsilon \le \epsilon f(x)<(n+1)\epsilon\})=\sum_{n\ge 1}\epsilon n\mu(\{x:n \le  f(x)<(n+1)\})+ \sum_{n\ge 1}\epsilon \mu(\{x:n \le  f(x)<(n+1)\})+\epsilon \mu(\{x:0\le f(x)<\epsilon\})$.

Can I show that $\epsilon \mu(\{x:0\le f(x)<\epsilon\}$ converges to zero?

Comment: Is $\mu$ finite? You can write $\int_Xf\,\mathrm d\mu=\int_{X\cap f^{-1}\langle[0,1)\rangle}f\,\mathrm d\mu+\int_Xf\,\mathbf 1_{\{f\ge1\}}\,\mathrm d\mu$ and use that the first integral is at most $\mu(X)$. I think you need $\mu(A_0)<\infty$ in full generality.

Comment: Yes his is a finite measure space.

Comment: So is it enough to say that $\mu (A_0)<\infty$ because $A_0\subset X$?

Comment: $\sum_{n\ge 1}n\mu(\{x:n\le f(x)<n+1\})$ is a _number_, not a statement. So saying "If $\sum_{n\ge 1}n\mu(\{x:n\le f(x)<n+1\})$ then..." makes exactly as much sense as saing "If 5 then...".

Comment: I forgot to add the inequality, but I edited the question.

Comment: Yes, $A_0\subset X$, so $\mu(A_0)\le\mu(X)<\infty$.